# How to tween the brightness of a movieclip in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, transform, tween, brightness

I have it so if your character touches CUBE instance, your character's brightness will be set to -0.15.

How do I tween it down to the brightness instead of instant?

```
if(char.hitTestObject(CUBE)){
    color.brightness = -0.15;
    char.transform.colorTransform = color;
}else{
    color.brightness = 0;
    char.transform.colorTransform = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some ac3 tweening platform or write it on your own. For example you could use [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/). We code will something like this.

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;



if(char.hitTestObject(CUBE)){
    TweenMax.to(char, 1, {colorTransform:{brightness:-0.15}});
}else{
    TweenMax.to(char, 1, {colorTransform:{brightness:0}});
}
```